# Can $\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf r_i^T \big (\sum_{j=1}^N \mathbf r_j \mathbf r_j^T \big)^{-1} \mathbf r_i$ be simplified?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $\{\mathbf r_i \in \mathbb R^n \}_{i=1\dots N}$ be some linearly independent column-vectors. I think it must be possible to simplify the expression

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf r_i^T \big (\sum_{j=1}^N \mathbf r_j \mathbf r_j^T \big)^{-1} \mathbf r_i,
$$

to a constant, however I am unsure.

Note that the bracketed term is a rank-$N$ matrix. You can safely assume here that $N > n$ so that the inverse exists.

Can this expression be reduced to a constant? Please (dis)prove or provide a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quantity (I'll call it $Q$) is a number, but think of it as the trace of the matrix $\sum r_i^T M^{-1} r_i$ where $M=\sum r_i r_i^T$.  But $\operatorname{tr} (AB)=\operatorname{tr} (BA),$ so $$Q = \operatorname{tr} \left(M^{-1} \sum r_i r_i^T \right)= \operatorname{tr} (M^{-1} M) = \operatorname{tr} I = n.$$

Comment: Thank you. It is only vaguely clear to me why $Q = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf r_i^T M^{-1} \mathbf r_i = \text{tr}(M^{-1} M)$. Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Let $x$ be a column vector.  The number $q=x^T x$ is $\operatorname{tr} x^T x $ and also $q=\operatorname{tr}x x^T$.  In the former case we have the trace of a $1\times 1$ matrix, in the latter of a $n\times n$ matrix.  But you can check that these two formulas give the same result for $q$, namely $q=\sum x_i^2$.  Your $Q$ is built from sums of such terms.

Comment: That is a very remarkable observation!